# How to access or mount .vdi in Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos, virtualbox, mount, vdi

Is there a working way to mount or access with read and write permissions VDI disk on Mojave? I've tried to use Paragon VDMK Mounter (no longer supported), no luck with it. Just says that mounted disk is not readable.

There's new product from Paragon: *Image Mounter by Paragon Software* but the registration is always failing on their website.

I've had luck with samba and sshfs, but most of the time I need to access guest's files with machine turned off.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sadly, I haven't figured it out